# Create an array from member of a structure array

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I have an array (let's call it `RateT`) of the following structure which gets filled after being read from disc.

```
/* tabulated rates */
typedef struct
{
  double Temperature, LAMBDA, townY;
  double townY_inv, Temperature_invY;
} RateTable;
```

I create an array of RateTable using the following.

```
RateTable* RateT = (RateTable *) malloc( NCOOLTAB * sizeof(RateTable));
```

Now in a different function (say `double Lambda(double* Temperature)`), I wish to pass an array that is made from say all the `Temperature` elements from each of the members of `RateT` array. Is there a neat and concise way to pass that as an argument to the function?

Comment: No it's not really possible. You need to create a brand new array, and copy from each structure into the new temperature array in a loop.

Comment: By the way, in C you don't need to (and really shouldn't) [cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).